# AngularJS - ngmaxlength not working with ng-required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-maxlength

Input Type

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required }">
    <label for="password">{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }} <span class="required-field"> *</span></label>
    <input uib-tooltip="{{ 'PLEASE_ENTER_PASSWORD' | translate }}" tooltip-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" type="password"
    name="password" id="password" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="password" ng-maxlength="5" required />
    <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">{{ 'PASSWORDISREQUIRED' | translate }}</span>
    <span ng-if="!loginForm.password.$valid" class="help-block">The maximum length for password is 5 characters</span>
</div>
```

When `ng-maxlength` is being used with `required` or `ng-required`, it shows the error message for characters limit even when nothing is typed in input. Instead it should show the error message only when input characters exceed the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to `!loginForm.password.$valid && loginForm.password.$error.maxlength`

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required }">
  <label for="password">{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }} <span class="required-field"> *</span></label>
  <input uib-tooltip="{{ 'PLEASE_ENTER_PASSWORD' | translate }}" tooltip-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="password" ng-maxlength="5" required />
  <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">{{ 'PASSWORDISREQUIRED' | translate }}</span>
  <span ng-if="!loginForm.password.$valid && loginForm.password.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">The maximum length for password is 5 characters</span>
</div>
```

Otherwise it will show it if the field has ANY error, which it has (empty required field).

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module("my-app", []);
app.controller("my-controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.loginForm = null;
  $scope.password = "";
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="my-controller" ng-form="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required }">
    <label for="password">Password <span class="required-field"> *</span></label>
    <input data-trigger="hover" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="color-tooltip form-control" ng-model="password" ng-maxlength="5" required />
    <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    <span ng-if="!loginForm.password.$valid && loginForm.password.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">The maximum length for password is 5 characters</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the condition `loginForm.password.$error.maxlength` worked ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I thought I did. `!loginForm.password.$valid` will be `true` if the field has ANY error, so the text will show if `required` is not met. Now we have added another check to see if `maxlength` specifically is the error.